# Bug in code using boost named_semaphore

Tags: c++, boost, semaphore, interprocess

I would keep some data in shared memory, using named semaphores to manage access:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_semaphore.hpp>

struct shared_memory_buffer
{
    // Application data
    int  items[10];

    // Synchronization data
    boost::interprocess::named_semaphore  syncSem;

    shared_memory_buffer()
    : syncSem(boost::interprocess::open_or_create_t, "testSemaphore", 0)   // error
    {}
};
```

However I get the following compile time error at the indicated line:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
```

This is my system:

MacOS X 10.6

i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)

Boost 1.44

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boost::interprocess::open_or_create_t` is a type – you presumably want to pass `boost::interprocess::open_or_create`, which of course is *an instance* of `open_or_create_t`. This is documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/interprocess/indexes_reference.html#header.boost.interprocess.creation_tags_hpp).